# Unexpected output (Python exercise)

Tags: python

My code is not printing the correct result for the test case

```
`2 6
1 alex
1 Alex
2 sam
1 alix
1 Alix
2 caM `
```

as it should result in "alex, sam", yet it results in "alex, Alex" (After reading the following instructions youll understand why). Was hoping I can get some insight as to what is wrong with my code.

**Exercise:** Dan’s recently announced that he’s teaching n top-secret courses next semester. Instead of enrolling in them through ACORN, students need to email Dan to express their interests. These courses are numbered from 1 to n in some arbitrary order. In particular, if a student named s is interested in taking a course c, they need to send an email to Dan containing the message c s. Note that if a student is interested in taking multiple courses, they need to send multiple emails, one per course. Upon receiving a message c s, Dan looks at the list of students already enrolled in course c. If there’s already a student on the list whose name is too similar to s, Dan assumes s is the same student and ignores the message. Otherwise, he enrolls s in the course. Dan considers two names too similar if and only if they have the same length and differ in at most one letter(note that “a” and “A” are considered the same letter). For example, “Josh” and “Josh” are too similar. “Sam” and “CaM” are too similar as well. However, neither “Max” and “Cat” nor “Ann” and “Anne” are too similar. Dan has a lot of students and teaches a lot of courses. Consequently, it would take him forever to process the messages sent by the students one-by-one manually. Instead, he’s asking you to help him out by writing a program that takes in the messages as the input and outputs, for every course, the list of the students enrolled in that course in the order of their enrolments.

****My code thus far: ****

```
`u = input()
u, w = u.split()
courses = int(u)
students = int(w)
names = []
classes = []

for i in range(students):
    names_input = input()
    selection = names_input.split()
    course_num = selection[0]
    student_name = selection[1]

    if course_num not in classes:
        classes.append(course_num)
        names.append(student_name)
    else:
        if student_name not in names:
            names.append(student_name)

    print(classes)
    print(names)

for i in range(0, len(classes)):
    print(names[i])
`
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the name to lower or upper case.
Because to python alex and Alex are different things. You can convert a string to lowercase using the string method `lower()`.

Like this :
`student_name = selection[1].lower()`

Comment: Oh ok. which line would i incorporate that? and would this solve my code completely?

Comment: `student_name = selection[1].lower()`

Comment: alright ill throw it in and see what happens, should fix everything haha